# iframe scroll bar not appearing in IE7

Tags: iframe, scrollbar

I have the following code:

```
<td colspan="7"height=200 valign="top">
<iframe id="myframe" name="myframe" src="index.php?page=1" width=810 height="100" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto"></iframe> 
</td>
```

I have don't see any scoll bar, either vertically or horizontally.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are there any fancy CSS properties on body for the iframe's contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only see a scrollbar in the iFrame if the page you are opening in the iFrame is bigger than the size of the iFrame.  Therefore, if 'index.php?page=1' will fit on a 810x100 window than the iFrame won't have any scrollbars.  If you are expecting to see a scrollbar in the td that holds the iFrame you would need to style it differently.  You would need to add style='overflow:auto' to the td that holds the iFrame.  By doing this you are telling that td that if it's content is larger than it's max height and width it should have scrollbars.

Comment: The style thing fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This renders a horizontal and vertical scrollbar for me in IE7:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td colspan="7"height=200 valign="top">
<iframe id="myframe" name="myframe" src="http://www.google.se" width=810 height="100" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="1" scolling="auto"></iframe> 
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```